# Renting a holiday house in the Riviera with a small child

Tags: france, children, rental, french-riviera

Where is the best place to do holiday rentals for a holiday house in the Riviera? Any particular webpage or operator would be appreciated.

We are considering somewhere between Antibes and Nice, but other or better suggestions are welcome. Time of year has to be July/August, because of a small child and work.

Any other suggestions or experiences are also welcome. We do not speak French for example. Might this be a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are usually traveling with our 3 year old kids. In all other area's of France we just go unprepared. Finding either a bed & breakfast or a holiday rental is relatively easy and in the summer we just go camping. This is not the case in the south of France, especially in the  summer months.

I have good experiences with [Google maps](http://maps.google.be/maps?q=holiday%20rental&hl=nl&ll=43.621165,7.25235&spn=0.572629,0.909119&sll=44.006645,7.566833&sspn=1.137889,1.818237&gl=be&t=m&hq=holiday%20rental&z=10) and [Tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/VRACSearch?inDay=16&bathroomsAlt=0&geo=187217&save=true&formGeo=1&tab=&pid=4455&sleeps=0&bedrooms=-1&inMonth=02/2013&checkIn=dd/mm/yyyy&outDay=23&checkOut=dd/mm/yyyy&searchAll=true&token=765f48a038d3bbe280a522344c6416cf&q=Antibes,%20France&outMonth=02/2013&insertFeatured=) to secure holiday rentals ahead of time. The trick with google maps is strait forward. You first identify the area you want to go by just zooming in our out. Then type either holiday rental, self catering apartment, or gites.

There is a Dutch website aimed at parents with very small children, called [petitparadis](http://www.petitparadis.nl/zoek_op_kaart_cote_dazur_languedoc_roussillon.php). This specific site does not have an english translation (other then the automatic Google translate), but being part of eurocamp, you can pinpoint their suggestion on their Dutch page and look for the details on the eurocamp.co.uk site. For the Riviera they suggest [La Baume](http://www.eurocamp.co.uk/sites/france-riviera-provence/rv014-la-baume.html).

Be aware that during the summer holidays, the temperature during the day can be quite high and with lots of sun and small kids you are pinned to your apartment for the better part of the afternoon to prevent extensive sun exposure. Personally I would say that the south of France with small kids is better to visit earlier or later in the season. In hindsight I rather went to the [Ardeche](http://maps.google.nl/maps?q=ardeche&hl=nl&ie=UTF8&sll=52.469397,5.509644&sspn=1.927563,3.636475&hnear=Ard%C3%A8che,%20Rh%C3%B4ne-Alpes,%20Frankrijk&t=m&z=8) last summer.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Lots of useful information here. La Baume looks really nice and we will look closer at it.

Answer (score 4):

Since this area is very touristy, not speaking French is not a major problem. You shall find people speaking a least bit of English in most places.

I do not really know a place to stay that would be more kid-friendly (how old is the kid, do you expect specific facilities such as playground near the place?). Since you will need a car to move around anyway, maybe you'd prefer to go more in the back-country for a more peaceful environment (avoid Juan-les-Pins/Antibes in this case and drive there just to go to the beach).

I can tell there are nice things to do in the area with kids, especially [Marineland](http://www.marineland.fr/page-_en.php) and some other parks around.

Comment: She is just 2 years old, so a special kid facility is not really needed. However, Marineland looks great so we will check it out. Thanks for the tips!